# mobile cross platform 2d game engine with several extra features

Tags: mobile, 2d, cross-platform, game-engine

I have few ideas for really simple games that I want to try and code.
I know C/C++/Java/PHP/AS3/Python and few more (and learning a new one isn't really a problem).
I'm looking for a game engine that can give me these features:

- cross platform (possibly write once run anywhere solution) simple development env that runs on win 7 (or linux, but I prefer win 7)
- I need access to in-app purchases/ads/splash screen and any other way to monetize
- facebook/whatsapp integration (simple share options, or invite friends in fb)
- ability to connect to database (mySql)
- ability to connect to some sort of server (TCP/IP, or just fetch any data from certain URL)
- 2d graphics, simple lines and shapes drawing, text and numbers writing
- most games have timers, so I need good response time when clicking a button or any other place on the screen (i guess that rules out Phonegap)

try to think I want to develop a simple card memory game with 5 seconds timer for each time you try to get a pair.

any ideas?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try unreal engine 4 :)
it's editor is amazing

one example project is actually that memory card game :)

you can code in c++ and/or you can use blueprints, which is a visual interface to define your game by connecting boxes in an UML like fashion. Its quite easy even for people with no coding background thus collaborating with non-coders can get quite productive.

looks, usability, tons of features, cross-platform.

its not free, but you can get away with a single month subscription fee, which is 20$ or 25$...
and if you sell your game they get a 5% cut. which is ok I guess.

Answer (score -1):

AS3 is easy to learn and its community is still alive :)

To me it is currently the most exciting cross platform technology out there at that time...

I would also recommend using the GPU accelerated 2D Framework Starling http://gamua.com/starling/

Then use ANE (Adobe Native Extensions) for all platform specific transactions such as Facebook integration or in app purchases.

Check out a simple 2 day project available on web/ios/android with one single code base: http://flappy-turd.com

Good Luck!